# Eject OTG Storage with ADB Command

Tags: adb, shell, usb-on-the-go

When I plug in an OTG cable with a flash drive attached to the other side, the system automatically mounts the drive.
How can I eject the OTG drive with a shell command? (Not Settings->Storage->Eject OTG)

Comment: Did you try `umount` command?

Comment: Did you read this thread yet? https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2086313.html

Comment: @esQmo Of course I've read that thread and given it a try but to no avail.

Comment: @GokulNC `umount` only detaches the mounted filesystem, but never ejects the drive.